# Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory - Angular Universal SSR with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal

So I'm following this [Server Side Rendering with Angular, Angular Universal, & Firebase 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7pLxaKkHYs&t=186s&ab_channel=Codeible) tutorial. Basically, to deploy my Angular universal project to Firebase hosting via Firebase functions.

I got as far as running the emulator to check that everything was fine. But, an error pop-up:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/Users/...
```

I suspect that is how I imported the express app into the functions that are wrong:

index.js - path directory: dist/functions/index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const mainjsFile = require(__dirname + "/server/main");
exports.ngssr = functions.https.onRequest(mainjsFile.app());
```

while the main.js lives in the server folder at - path directory: dist/functions/server/main.js

Please, if someone could shine some light on this as I have been trying to resolve it for days.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the `distFolder` value in the `server.ts` file.

- locate the file `server.ts`. This file is added to the project when you run the command to add Angular Universal
- For the distFolder, replace the project name with `functions`. We need to do this because we need to tell the server where to look to find the files for our pages, and they are inside the folder called `browser`. `const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), "dist/functions/browser");`

However, this path will only work if you are testing locally on the computer.
When we’re in the testing environment, the root directory is where the `server.ts` file is, and your website files are in the `dist/functions/browser` directory.

**But** when you deploy the project to Cloud functions, the root directory will change and it’ll be the `functions` directory. The website files will no longer be in the path you defined earlier.

To fix this, create a variable and use the production property in the environment object to check if you are in test or production mode.

If you are in the production environment, return `browser` because the web files are located in the `browser` folder. If not, return `dist/functions/browser`:

`const websiteFileLocation = environment.production? "browser" : "dist/functions/browser";`

- Replace the string for the distFolder with the variable and save the project:

  `const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), websiteFileLocation );`